# Convert exponential large number to normal integer in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Number to Convert : 1.30101200030211E+36

Desired output : 1301012000302111211122323112113333013

what i have tried :

```
Text(cellNo, 0) = 1301012201010220000000000000000000000

TRIM(cellNo) =  1.30101111020201E+36
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately Excel doesn't support arbitrary precision, [maximum precision is 15 digits](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1#bmcalculation). Your only chance is to insert the number as text, and once your try to convert it to number you'll loose last digits.

Comment: Are you going to use the expanded form of the number in any calculation which requires high accuracy?

Comment: Its a barcode number, which required to be as it is.
I am downloading data as csv, i can download as xml as well. In google sheet it is fine. But when opening in local system, it again convert to exponential form. due to this data is migrating in same form.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a value in a cell like:

[image]

Then you can display it as an **integer** just by changing the format:

[image]

But if you really need to enter or import something as massive as:

*1301012000302111211122323112113333013*

then you must enter or import it as `Text`:

**EDIT#1:**

To import the value as `Text`, just tell the Import Wizard what to do:

[image]

Comment: How to import as text ? bcz i have csv file. above one i already tried.

Comment: @Ankuli  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: To import a .csv and get the import wizard, change the file extension to .txt then excel will open with import wizard and you can define a column as text

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as the OP, the barcode numbers were shown in exponential format. Selecting the whole column and changing it to number with 0 decimals did the trick. It was more than 25000 lines that I'd have to change manually, so doing this saved me a LOT of time!